# Как сделать автоматическое обновление программы на новую версию?

Tags: обновление, delphi, delphi-7, borland

У меня программа автоматически проверяется на версию. Возможно ли такое, чтоб в случае новой версии она автоматически скачивала бы новую и заменялась на неё? Если да, то как? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это, конечно же, возможно. Раз это вопрос новичка в Delphi, то постараюсь ответить доходчиво, как такое реализовать.

- Для начала вам нужно завести хостинг
     или аккаунт на каком-л. облачном
     хранилище. Это необходимо для того,
     чтобы программа имела в сети "свой
     уголок", откуда могла бы проверять
     новую версию и самообновляться в
     случае появления новой. Лично я вам
     советую заводить именно хостинг,
     нежели пользоваться услугами
     "облаков", так как у этих облачных
     хранилищ очень ограничена [пропускная
     способность канала](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%F0%EE%EF%F3%F1%EA%ED%E0%FF_%F1%EF%EE%F1%EE%E1%ED%EE%F1%F2%FC), а если
     пользователей у вашей "программы"
     будет очень много, то аккаунт забанят
     из-за большого трафика. Пользуйтесь
     хостингом.
- Далее вам надо создать на этом
     хостинге файлик, в котором будет
     лежать текущая(последняя) версия
     вашего "продукта". **Например,
     1.72.**. И еще, конечно же, на хостинг надо поместить "свежую"
     версию вашего "продукта", чтобы можно
     было её скачать.
- Далее в самой программе вы должны
     каждый раз при запуске проверять
     версию из того файла на хостинге,
     который содержит версию. В самой
     программе, естественно, должна быть
     константа, содержащая номер версии
     программы. Это можно сделать с
     помощью TIdHttp с панели IndyClients.
     Если версия больше, то качаем
     новую(расположена на нашем хостинге.
- Качать новую версию лучше всего из
     "вспомогательной" програмки,
     прилагаемой к основному файлу вашего
     "приложения". В случае обнаружения
     новой версии запускаем updator и он
     уже все сам сделает.
- Что будет делать апдейтор? Он, в
     случае обнаружения новой версии,
     будет закрывать основное
     "приложение", скачивать новое(Как?
     Это вам должно быть известно.) и
     копировать его вместо старого.
     Скачанный файл потом надо будет
     удалить.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov а зачем обновлять апдейтер??)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а зачем его менять? Ведь его задача будет маленькая( но немаловажная ) - обновить основной файл программы и закрыться, как будто бы его и нет...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, ну большинство этих "вещиц" можно сделать "динамически изменяемыми". Так, например, можно на хостинге создать файл параметров, где будет вся инфа по подключению к БД, прочим серверам, если надо и т.д.

---
А вообще, раз уж так может понадобиться обновлять апдейтор, то можно просто "схитрить" и сделать "взаимное обновление". То есть, например, при надобности основное приложение обновит тот апдейтор, а тот, в свою очередь, будет обновлять само приложение. Вариант здесь не один, на самом деле =)

Comment: чем больше компонент, тем сложнее становится система. в итоге превращается в слипшиеся макароны. идите сразу простым путем. некоторые ваще не парятся по поводу автообновлений, хотите новую версию - качайте, ставьте руками...

Comment: Юра Иванов, вообщем-то вы правы =). Париться с этим особо не надо, если ты пишешь легальную софтину. В ином случае( вы понимаете, о чем я) ) - только автообновление!

Comment: Судя по вопросам, ТС пишет не вирус, а что-то типа "калькулятор", но со всеми возможными и невозможными примочками - и автообновление и прятание в трей, скоро появятся вопросы про круглую форму/кнопку, таскание формы за любую область окна и т.д. В итоге программа будет скорее всего бесполезной, но в ней будет все остальное.

Comment: > Париться с этим особо не надо, если ты пишешь легальную софтину

> некоторые ваще не парятся по поводу автообновлений

Автоматические обновления это очень важная деталь, на мой взгляд, показывающая степень зрелости софта (главным образов мире десктопных windows-приложений, но не только). Не всякий пользователь может самостоятельно скачать и поставить обновление. Более того, пользователь может вообще не узнать о важных обновлениях, если не предусмотреть эту систему.

Comment: > что делать если меняется и сам "апдейтор"?

И почему апдейтер не сможет обновить себя аналогичным образом? Апдейтер WoW как-то с эти всегда справлялся.

Comment: @Nofate, в мире windows это становится практически невозможно, так как преграда - UAC! Если он включен( а включен он, как я потом узнал на 88% машин ), то автоматическое обновление становится невозможным без уведомления пользователя.

---
**Mozilla FireFox**, например, умеет обходить UAC, используя один из его многочисленных багов - переполнение буфера =)

Comment: @Asen, так это же прекрасно. Разве нет?

Comment: @Nofate Вопросы были наводящими. Вопрос был не "почему не сможет обновиться?", а "как его будем обновлять?". Для новичка не только дельфи, но вообще новичка, не является очевидным как запущенной программе перезаписать себя. апдейтер WoW тут ни при чем.

Что касается обязательности автообновления - это религиозный момент. Кому-то они нравятся, кому-то и без обновлений неплохо живется. Это фича, а не мастхэв.

Прикольно было бы если б у меня весь установленный на компе софт разом бы автообновился на последнюю версию, в том числе и винда.

Comment: @Хэшкод, Опять кто-то мои комментарии потер. О чем речь теперь можно только догадываться.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, этим занимается Asen, потому как критика сильно уязвляет нашего *специалиста по безопасности*. Например, нельзя смеяться над след. волшебной фразой:

> Mozilla FireFox, например, умеет обходить UAC, используя один из его многочисленных багов - переполнение буфера

Answer (score 4):

[@Asen](/users/5040/asen) все неплохо расписал. Разве что могут возникнуть трудности с пунктами 3-4. Чтобы облегчить себе жизнь вы можете воспользоваться компонентом [TWebUpdate](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/wupdate.asp).

Он поможет вам собирать пакеты обновлений, умеет обнаруживать обновления на вашем сервере, загружать их по FTP, HTTP, HTTPS, выводить информацию (вашу) об обновлении, подменять exe-шник, избавляя вас от заморочек с UAC-ом в Windows Vista/7.

Comment: Компонент очень даже неплохой. Лучше даже использовать именно его...только вот одна проблемка есть - компонент-то не штатный, а значит придется изучать, что да как в нем работает и как вообще его юзать. Но это в любом случае плюс =)

Answer (score 0):

Я писал автоматическое обновление для своего проекта, проще покажу схему.![alt text][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOxcV.png Тут все в принципе по схеме понятно. Исходники и полное описание кода я привел в статье http://myshinobi.ru/kak-sdelat-obnovlenie-programmy-na-delphi/. Плюсы описаной схемы -проверяется корректность скачанного файла - при неудачно закачке автоматический откат. Минусы - нет докачки и - скачивается один файл.